# Find and replace hyperlinks to external sources

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have Word files in which I need to replace hyperlinks to external sources.

I have a table in a separate Word document where column 1 is the document name (the displayed text, I hope) and column 2 is the URL.

I want to search the files for the document name in column 1, and add/replace the existing URL with the contents of column 2.
Ideally, I'd like to highlight this to see where it has worked and where it has not.

The code does not produce an error, but doesn't add the hyperlink either.

```vb
Sub Links()

Dim oTable As Table
Dim oRng As Range
Dim rFindText As Range, rReplacement As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim sFname As String

sFname = "myexternaltablespathway.docx"
Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
Set oChanges = Documents.Open(FileName:=sFname, Visible:=False)
Set oTable = oChanges.Tables(1)
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

For i = 1 To oTable.Rows.Count
    Set oRng = oDoc.Range
    Set rFindText = oTable.Cell(i, 1).Range
    rFindText.End = rFindText.End - 1
    Set rHyperlink = oTable.Cell(i, 2).Range
    rHyperlink.End = rHyperlink.End - 1
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    With oRng.Find
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Text = (rFindText.Text)
        .Highlight = True

        ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rFindText, Address:= _
          "rHyperlink"

        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
Next i
oChanges.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't call `Execute` to actually run the search?

Answer (score 0):

Plz try this:

```vb
Sub Links()
    
    Dim oDoc As Document, oChanges As Document
    
    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim oRng As Range
    
    'Dim rFindText As Range, rReplacement As Range
    Dim rFindText As String, rHyperlink As String
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sFname As String
    
    sFname = "myexternaltablespathway.docx"'this sFname must be a full name of the file
    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set oChanges = Documents.Open(FileName:=sFname, Visible:=False)
    Set oTable = oChanges.Tables(1)
'    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    
    For i = 1 To oTable.rows.Count
        Set oRng = oDoc.Range
        'Set rFindText = oTable.cell(i, 1).Range
        'rFindText.End = rFindText.End - 1
        rFindText = oTable.cell(i, 1).Range.Text
        rFindText = Left(rFindText, Len(rFindText) - 2)
        
        'Set rHyperlink = oTable.cell(i, 2).Range
        'rHyperlink.End = rHyperlink.End - 1
        rHyperlink = oTable.cell(i, 2).Range.Text
        rHyperlink = Left(rHyperlink, Len(rHyperlink) - 2)
        
        'Selection.HomeKey wdStory
        With oRng.Find
        
            Rem why use the wildcards?
            '.MatchWildcards = True
            
    '        .Text = (rFindText.Text)
            .Text = rFindText
            
'            .Highlight = True 'this will find the range be highlighted
            
'            ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rFindText, Address:= _
'                "rHyperlink" ' this line is wrong!!!
            
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop 'wdFindContinue
            .Execute
            Do While .Found()
                If .Parent.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim lnk As Hyperlink
                    For Each lnk In .Parent.Hyperlinks
                        lnk.Delete
                    Next lnk
                End If
                .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=oRng, _
                                    Address:=rHyperlink
                .Parent.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                .Parent.SetRange .Parent.End, oDoc.Range.End
                .Execute
            Loop
        End With
    Next i
    oChanges.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```